# Understanding ArcMap automatic rematching?

Tags: arcmap, geocoding

I am geocoding fairly large data using ArcGIS. I had a considerate amount (16%) of locations had tied results after geocoding using a composite address locator using multiple fields. I am curious what criteria ArcMap use when you hit the "Rematch automatically" button.

Is it choosing the one with the highest score? Will the results of matched records, especially the matched with tied candidates, change after I hit the "Rematch automatically"?

Just want to make sure I know how it is processing the automatic rematch before I use it since this process cannot be undone.

Comment: I think you should test this on a copied subset to see whether it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The following information is pulled from the ArcMap 10.x documentation on http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/geocoding/rematching-a-geocoded-feature-class-about.htm

It appears that unless you change the geocoding options, "rematch automatically" will use the original geocoding settings and essentially re-geocode the locations. You can take a subset of the addresses that failed geocoding and change things like the minimum candidate score to allow this subset of fails to potentially get matched on this second attempt to geocode.

> Rematch Automatically button
>
> Clicking the Rematch Automatically button takes the current result set
>   and matches it automatically. If the result set contains a subset of
>   all the addresses, only the subset will be automatically rematched. If
>   the All Addresses result set is selected in the Show results drop-down
>   list, the entire address table is completely rematched, which is like
>   geocoding for the first time. The existing geocoding options are used
>   in the rematch process, which can be adjusted with the Geocoding
>   Options button on the bottom of the Interactive Rematch dialog box.
>
> For example, you might have several thousand business clients to
>   geocode for a spatial analysis, but you don't have much time to
>   accurately match everyone; however, you do want to ensure the clients
>   who generate the most revenue for your business are accurately
>   located. To accomplish this, you could plan a workflow that uses the
>   rematch automatically function with different result sets and
>   geocoding options.
>
> You could make two result sets: one for clients that generate between
>   $0 and $999 of revenue per year and one for clients that generate more
>   than $1,000 per year. After automatically geocoding the entire client
>   address list, you could open the Interactive Rematch dialog box,
>   choose the result set with the high-revenue clients (greater than
>   $1,000), and interactively rematch them. Next, you could select the
>   clients who generate under $1,000 from the Show results drop-down
>   list, relax the settings on the Geocoding Options dialog box, and
>   click Rematch Automatically. The result fits your priorities: less
>   time spent geocoding low-priority addresses at the cost of less
>   accurate results and more time spent geocoding high-priority addresses
>   with the benefit of more accurate results.